# Number of parameters based on variable

Tags: ruby, parameters

Is there a way have x amount of same parameters in Ruby?

Easiest way to ask this is, can you shorten this?

```
arr = [0,1,2,3]
if x == 1
    return arr
elsif x == 2
    return arr.product(arr)
elsif x == 3
    return arr.product(arr, arr)
elsif x == 4
    return arr.product(arr, arr, arr)
elsif x == 5
    return arr.product(arr, arr, arr, arr)
end
```

Comment: The most essential concept here is that you can use a "splat" (the asterisk `*`) to turn an array into sequential arguments.
The posted answer includes a good example of this.

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful, please consider selecting the one you preferred. (I'd prefer saying this if there were more than one answer, but the question is several days old...)

Answer (score 8):

You can obtain the desired result as follows.

```
def prod(arr, x)
  return arr if x==1
  arr.product(*[arr]*(x-1))
end

arr = [0,1,2,3]

arr                             == prod(arr, 1) #=> true
arr.product(arr)                == prod(arr, 2) #=> true
arr.product(arr, arr)           == prod(arr, 3) #=> true
arr.product(arr, arr, arr)      == prod(arr, 4) #=> true
arr.product(arr, arr, arr, arr) == prod(arr, 5) #=> true
```

Comment: A one liner `return x==1 ? arr : arr.product(*[arr]*(x-1))` :)

Comment: I'd probably use the [array constructor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-c-new) to avoid confusion between the two `*`'s, i.e. `arr.product(*Array.new(x - 1, arr))`